# Cannot set MemOpMode or ProcVirtualization with syscfg.exe

Tags: windows, dell, bios

When attempting to set `MemOpMode` or `ProcVirtualization` with syscfg.exe, I get the following error:

```
C:\Users\EGr>syscfg --MemOpMode=AdvEccMode
System Services or CSIOR disabled
```

In the past, I have been told that this can be resolved by forcefully reinstalling the Dell Lifecycle controller firmware, and then trying again; however, I cannot find my notes on how to do that. Has anyone ever run into this issue, and does anyone know how I can fix it? If it is possible to forcefully reinstall the firmware, how would I do that? I've tried running the installer, but it fails after running for ~2 min. I believe there is a way to fix this as well, by adding/modifying a registry value at `HKLM\System\Control\CurrentControlSet\Services\IPMIDRV` (that might not be the correct path, but I know it is IPMIDRV). Is this a common issue? What is the actual cause of it?

Answer (score 0):

After looking in the registry, and trying a few things I was able to get it to work. I was able to do it in the past with guidance from one of my team members; and I had just forgotten one of the steps; but here is the steps:

- Change the value of start (at HKLM/System/CurrentControlSet/Services/IPMIDRV) to 3
- Reboot
- Run the Lifecycle Controller firmware installer as local admin
- If there is an error about partitions, try a `racadm racreset` and wait for the device to come back online (when racadm getsysinfo no longer shows `<UNKNOWN>/` for the IP Address fields)

  - After this is successful, re-run the firmware installer as a local admin
- Reboot
- Change syscfg properties (ex: MemOpMode, ProcVirtualization)
- Change the IPMIDRV registry value back to 4 (or whatever you had it set at before you changed it)

I'm still not 100% certain what happened to make it fail initially, but this worked for me.